# IE6 overflow-x being ignored

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-6

Here's the site in question: http://cbcsettlementfunding.com/dev/

Almost finished up with development, just have a few bugs left to fix in IE6, one of which is particularly annoying: horizontal scrollbars on every page of the site.

- Firstly, I can't readily identify what is causing this since it's only happening in IE6 (7, 8, and 9 beta are unaffected).
- Secondly, the one trick I had hoped to quickly fix this issue for the time being, setting "overflow-x: hidden" on the html and body tags, isn't working either.

I've been staring at this code for days and can't find anything wrong, so I'm hoping it's just something small that I may have overlooked like forgetting to close a tag or something small.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `overflow: none;` Doesn't do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `<style type="text/css">#sb-container { left:0; }</style>` to the head section of your pages.

Comment: I don't know how, but this worked. Never thought Shadowbox would be the culprit here.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this might be considered as a non-answer, but if it's eating away at a lot of your time I would strongly recommend simply letting the scrollbars be. Unless the client has a substantial amount of IE6 traffic, this might be the perfect time to let "graceful degradation" take its toll. Especially since an extra scroll bar on the bottom (probably) isn't breaking the layout.

Comment: Normally that's the route I would take, but in this instance the large majority of people accessing this site would be using IE6... People that, in most cases, don't even have computers of their own and rely on public libraries and other city-run computer facilities for access.